# PSU shuts down when connecting a 200w LED array

Tags: power-supply, amperage, led-strip

My PSU is rated 45A on the 12v rail and my LED strips need 16.5A in total.
The array is driven from one single pin in a 6 pin molex connecter.

In theory, there is enough current for the array to run safely but my PSU shuts down after it ran for about a second. What might possibly cause the PSU to power off?

[image: 6 pin molex used to connect to the array]

Comment: I don't know if its OK by the ATX standard to just connect an insolated load to this line. Have you at least bridged the "on detect" pins on the main ATX connector?

Comment: Yes, I shorted those two pins (green + black) and got it working with lower loads before. Maybe drawing this much current on only one pin triggers a safety feature of the PSU.

Comment: No way those cables are OK with carrying 16.5A. Connect thicker cables straight to the PSU, or connect several in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that while your supply can deliver a total of 45A, internally, it is composed of multiple 12V rails that can each deliver a part of that 45A (for example, it might be a 12V 25A CPU rail and 2 other 12V 10A rails for graphics cards and the motherboard).

Additionally, you are drawing all this current from a single connector. Internally, the PSU might sense every connector or group of connectors separatly and it could be seeing the 16A you attempt to draw from this 12V rail as an overload condition (I don't think a 6pin PCI power connector is "allowed" to provide that much current).

Comment: Thats what i suspected as well, I guess trying the CPU 12v rail or combining multiple 12v pins might solve this.

Comment: When connecting multiple rails together, make sure to add a balance resistor to each to prevent one trying to force a lot of current into the other. A few tens of miliohm might be sufficient, but this ultimatly depends on the performance of your supply (how close the rails are)